# Data model that incorporates two different kind of relationships

Tags: data-modeling, relationship

I'm trying to find out which kind of data model i should use and how this data model should look like. The model needs to be stored in a relational database (SQL). And the language used: PHP.

I have several kinds of items: projects, tasks and reviews. In my final application there will be many types of items.

Each item (of any type) needs to be able to belong to another item (of any type) and each item (of any type) needs to be able to be the follow-up of another item (of any type). So i need two different kinds of relationships: inheritence and chronological; both are directed. No matter what kind of relationship items may not loopback onto themselves. Illegal: Item A -> Item B -> Item C -> Item A.

I want to be able to extract the following kind of information:

- Show me the chain of items that lead to this item. (chronological relationship) Output: List
- Show me all the items that belong to this item. (inheritence relationship) Output: Tree
- Show me how this item lead to that item (ignore items from other projects). (both chronological & inheritence relationship) Output: ??

I don't know how i would visualize the last one.

The user needs to be able to:

- Add/Remove an item (of any kind)
- Make/Break a relationship (of any kind)
- Change relationship or item type.

Comment: I wonder why you need that abstract data model based on Nodes. Wouldn't a more concrete data model based on Tasks, Projects and Reviews be enough? Are you planning to apply some sort of graph algorithms to your data model? Could you elaborate a bit on the usage scenarios of your data model?

Comment: I edited in some considerations, if that doesn't answer your questions let me know.

Comment: Still I do not see the requirement for approaching the problem with a generic data model based on Nodes (and Edges aka Graph). Overall you should add some context information. Are you seeking an OO model, a relational model, anything else? Why? What's the technical context the model should be implemented in? (Programming language? Is it part of an application? What are use cases for that application?) What kinds of information you need to extract from the model and what's the behaviour you need to model?

Comment: Changed again. If anything is missing then give an example of the kind of information that is missing because i put everything as best as i could from your questions earlier.

Comment: Yes, things are much clearer now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how this could be a problem through a relational conceptual design.
You can always get the information in forms you're seeking by parsing through the output (from queries). e.g.

with the schema:

```
project(pid,...),
milestone(pid,mid),
tasks(tid,mid,..),
reviews(rid,tid,..),
events(evid,rid), ...
```

from a project, you can get the all the events which led to a review, or even all events related to a project(through joins), and then parse through them to arrange and display in whatever information format you like.

A user can always add & remove items. With your example, I couldn't yet get what 'change relationship or item type' would mean!

Comment: Excuse me, the extract information examples were specific for one type. I change my post once again to reflect that it does not matter which type of item you are connecting to another type of item.

Change item type EXAMPLE: Project becomes task.

Change relationship type EXAMPLE: Review belongs to a task, but this is incorrect because the review is not part of the task, it is the FOLLOW UP after the task (making the review can even be seen as a seperate task). Change: belong-to relationship to follow-up relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item(iid,itemstuff,typeid,iid)
type(typeid,description)
```

With itemstuff, you can add serializable data, or things you may like which are common. And then, if you wish, specialize:

```
Item1(iid,i1....)
item2(iid,i2....)
.
```

But then, changing would mean updating.

I had to do this once for a similar problem, but I didn't bother back then about loopbacks.
I seriously doubt you can get such a dynamic model in within rdbms.